# How do I get the HTML from an external page and dump in it a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, feed

I'm trying to solve an issue using jQuery. I'm wondering if its possible to get an external page's HTML and dump it in a div using jQuery?

For instance if the external `URL` desired was CNN.com--what would the code be to go to that page, fetch the HTML & output it to a div (the div has the id `#target`)?

Comment: See [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Do you want to create a feed?

Comment: The answer **must** involve a server-side proxy (such as PHP-cURL), do you have access to such technology?